# String Equality - What is going on here?

Tags: c#, string

In order to debug an issue in my code, I have declared the following two strings, assuming they would be equivalent:

```
String print = "8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717";
String newPrint = thumbprint.Trim().Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();
```

I discovered they are not. Great, this is the source of my issue. However, I'm checking things in the immediate window (on the line following the declarations) and don't understand what is happening. Here is the output:

```
print
"8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717"
newPrint
"‎8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717"
String.Compare(print, newPrint);
0
print == newPrint
false
print.Equals(newPrint)
false
```

huh? Why aren't they equal?

edit:

I need to use 'thumbprint' as the base. It's a user entered string. I'm just using 'newPrint' as a temporary variable to hold the trimmed/uppered value. print is the expected outcome.

Comment: thumbprint != print

Comment: Your first variable is "print", your second variable is based on "thumbprint" so they very well may not be equivalent. Is this just a typo?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth ignore what thumbprint is. it doesn't matter, look at the output.

Comment: Can you rewrite the question so it's unambiguous, pls ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew how is it ambiguous?

Comment: @Erix showed the values of `print` and `newPrint` and as we can see they are identical (`String.Compare` delivers the expected result). According to [MSDN: String.Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx) `String.Equals`should return `true`...

Comment: What does `String.Compare(print, newPrint, StringComparison.Ordinal);` return?

Comment: @Spontifixus: As you can see in my answer, they are in fact not identical. They just look the same.

Comment: This questions shows once more how important it is to copy & paste the code and output you really have, instead of typing something you think of as being "equivalent". If Erix would have done that, it would have been impossible for us to find out what is going on.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - you are right, I just looked at the code...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Indeed, they are not equivalent. I copied the two values and `newPrint` has a length of 41 whereas `print` has a length of 40. The first character of `newPrint` is a character with the ASCII value 14. Interesstingly, this has been transfered from your immediate window to SO to my LINQPad.

```
print.Length
40
newPrint.Length
41
(sbyte)print[0]
56
(sbyte)newPrint[0]
14
```

That actually has nothing to do with your `Trim` and `Replace` calls but with the fact that you are using `thumbprint` instead of `print` as the base. I can only assume that `thumbprint` contains that additional character. Where it comes from I don't know. If you would change your second line to use `print` instead of `thumbprint` you would get the result you expect.

Comment: Ahh yes, you can actually see it take 2 presses of left/right arrow in VS to move the cursor!

Comment: I see, thank you. apparently the characer is a 'Shift Out, alternate character set'. No idea what that's doing there...

Comment: ASCII 14 is the "SO" character - which was originally used to select different character sets. Not sure why on earth it would be popping up here though...

Comment: @Erix: I can't say anything about how it got there, sorry.

Comment: THis doesn’t explain why `String.Compare` returned 0 (= equal).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Right. That's what [Tigrans answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12407082/572644) is for.

Comment: @Daniel I don’t think that actually explains it either.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You are free to post your own answer.

Comment: @Daniel I have no idea why it works the way it does. In my understanding, it should give a result consistent with `Equals` here. I’d find it weird if a culture leads to characters being disregarded.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Aha. I think the explanation of Tigran makes sense. As String.Compare is culture dependant, it might treat different characters as equal (no pun intended), although they are not from a byte to byte perspective.

Comment: @Daniel Actually, I’ve just checked the documentation and the relevant description is this: “Character sets include ignorable characters. The Compare(String, String) method does not consider such characters when it performs a culture-sensitive comparison. For example, a culture-sensitive comparison of "animal" with "ani-mal" (using a soft hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates that the two strings are equivalent …”

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Nice find. That means that Tigrans explanation in fact is correct.

Comment: Ran a test `string.Equals("8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717","‎8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) // True` while `string.Equals("8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717","‎8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717") // False`

Answer (score 18):

The strings that you're posted are *not* equal. 
Just do this:

```
string val   = "8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717"; 
string val1  = "‎8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717";
var bt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val);
var bt_1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val1);
```

You will see that the second array contains more element in *begining*.

```
226 
128 
142
```

after this 3 elements content is equal.

The reason `String.Compare` works is cause:

> The comparison uses the current culture to obtain culture-specific
>   information such as casing rules and the alphabetic order of
>   individual characters

Comment: +1 for the explanation why String.Compare returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the question. If not, pl. specify the complete environment as I have tried this on MS .NET but not on Mono. 
Try this method: - I get no errors and the output of the trace statement is

> Strings are equal = True

```
void TestString()
{
    String print = "8A9B485ECDC56B6E0FD023D6994A57EEC49B0717";
    String newPrint = print.Trim().Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();
    Trace.TraceInformation("Strings are equal = {0}", (print == newPrint) && (print.Equals(newPrint)));
    Debug.Assert(print == newPrint);
    Debug.Assert(print.Equals(newPrint));
}
```

Comment: You are a bit late to the party. Please see the other two answers to know what was going on.